# Why does my pilot light on my propane wall heater get really small and after about 5 seconds goes out when I turn the setting up to a 3 or so?

Tags: heater, propane

Why does my pilot light get really low and after about 5-10 seconds go out when I turn the dial or setting up to about a 3 depending on how cold it is? I can turn it back down to a lower setting and it goes back to a normal flame, I haven’t replaced any parts and used this propane heater this heater has the bricks to not sure if that has anything to do with it

Comment: How cold is the bottle? Propane bottles don't flow if they get too cold.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The propane tank isn’t cold, it’s only been around 60 degrees here during the day but I can ignite and turn on my propane wall heater and the pilot light will stay lit on settings 1-2& even 3 bun til it’s suppose to heat the bricks (I guess that’s what they are called: the 3 white plaques on the back wall) the pilot light will either get really small or go completely out. I tried resetting the regulator, I tried adjusting the flame, I cleaned all the dust ( I believe), and I tried to clean the thermal coupler. I’m going to replace the regulator any suggestions what else I could do?